# What's the difference in backing binding properties with private fields or DependencyProperty?

Tags: c#, uwp, dependency-properties

I have some philosophical question for you:

In my UWP apps, currently I usually define binding properties as follows:

```
public class ExampleViewModel : BaseBind {

    // Pattern used for two-way bindings
    private object exampleObject;  // Private field for backing a binding propery
    public Object ExampleObject {
        get { return exampleObject; }
        set {
            SetProperty(ref exampleObject, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ExampleDerivateProperty));
        }
    }

    // Simple derivate property, used in One-way bindings
    public Object ExampleDerivateProperty => (<<Boolean function about ExampleObject>>)? "Something" : "Something different";

}
```

That's it... this is all that I currently use in my MVC pattern.

...but I noticed that many prefer using DependencyProperty for backing their binding properties:

```
public string MyProperty
{

    get { return (string)GetValue(MyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyProperty, value); }

}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(string), typeof(MyControl), null);
```

What new interesting functions could I obtain if I would use DependencyProperties instead of simple private fields?

I know that this question could seem already answered here on StackOverflow, but this particular case may be interesting to delve into, even with some example.

Thanks.

EDIT: I know there already are some answers to this topic, but they're mostly outdated, because now we have the UWP platform, which features "x:Bind" compile binding and many other things have been added to C#.
I would like to know if something has changed since then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use Dependency Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104154/when-to-use-dependency-properties)

Comment: @WaiHaLee, yes, but that was back in 2010 and C# has evolved in the past few years: UWP platform was created, which features new "x:Bind" that I commonly use for XAML binding... so, I thought that this question may require an updated answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What new interesting functions could I obtain if I would use DependencyProperties instead of simple private fields?

Classes with dependency properties must inherit from `DependencyObject` and this has some drawbacks which are summarized here:

[INotifyPropertyChanged vs. DependencyProperty in ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291518/inotifypropertychanged-vs-dependencyproperty-in-viewmodel)

They can only be accessed from a single thread for example.

In general, a *view model* shouldn't contain any dependency properties. Only *target* properties are typically defined as dependency properties. Target properties are such properties that you bind something to in the *view*, for example the `Text` property of a `TextBlock`.

`x:Bind` has nothing to do with choosing between CLR and dependency source properties really. It's a markup extension in UWP that converts your XAML bindings into code at compile-time for performance reasons.

Comment: Good... if you could include some example of DependencyProperty and it's use (VS IDE states that they allows Animations, Templates, etc.), it would be great.